# Unable to populate dynamic textbox value based on dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and am trying to populate my textbox to dynamically change its value when I select the dropdownList. My code is able to compile and run successfully with the exception that nothing appears on the textbox.

I would appreciate any kind advice.

Thank you.

*Attached is my code

```
<body>
            <select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList" onchange="getSelectValue();">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select>

        <input type="text" id="price" value="" disabled> //I'm trying to change this value

        <br>
        <script>
            function getSelectValue() {
                var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
                if(selectedValue.equals("Volvo")) {
                    document.getElementById("price").value = "4.50";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("price").value = "3.50";
                }
            }
        </script>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`selectedValue.equals` is not a function in javascript you use `if(selectedValue == 'volvo')` instead of `if(selectedValue.equals("Volvo"))`.

And also Value of select box is `volvo` not `Volvo`.

```
<script>
function getSelectValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
  if(selectedValue == 'volvo') {
      document.getElementById("price").value = "4.50";
   } else {
  document.getElementById("price").value = "3.50";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Better to give the explanation why your code is working and OP code is not.

Comment: Its the equals.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
  <script>
        function getSelectValue() {
            var selectedValue = document.getElementById("dropdownList").value;
            console.log(selectedValue);
            if(selectedValue==="volvo") {
                document.getElementById("price").value = "4.50";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("price").value = "3.50";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` when comparing, not `.equals`.

Casing matters. If the `option` value is `'volvo'`, don't test against `'Volvo'`.

Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#dropdownList')
select.addEventListener('change', getSelectValue);

function getSelectValue() {
  var selectedValue = select.value;
  if (selectedValue === "volvo") {
    document.getElementById("price").value = "4.50";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("price").value = "3.50";
  }
}
getSelectValue();
```

```html
<select id="dropdownList" name="dropdownList">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price" value="" disabled>
```